# Binding error in VS2010 XAML designer, yet runs fine generally

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml

Sorry for the vague(ish) title, I'm working on a WPF project, and it's getting rather annoying. I know that the VS designer is a bit finickity at times, but hoping it's something that I can fix.

I've got a dependency property that I'm putting a binding too, however the designer is giving me blue squiggles and an error:

`Error  13  A 'Binding' cannot be used within a 'TextBlock' collection. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.`

However when I run the app, it's all working fine, no binding errors for that, the it all works as expected. VS has been restarted many times since it first happened, and it still occurs.

I can't see anything wrong with the DependancyProperty that it's referring to, all looks pretty standard to me, but maybe one of you guys can shed some light (hopefully). I cannot remember where I got the code for the DP from, I know it was online, but I've tweaked slighty from that (I think).

Running VS2010, project is targeting .net4.0 (not the Client Profile).

Thanks!

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" AllowDrop="True" behaviours:DropBehavior.PreviewDropCommand="{Binding Path=DropFile}" Style="{StaticResource styFile}">
```

**DP**

```
public static class DropBehavior {

    private static readonly DependencyProperty PreviewDropCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "PreviewDropCommand",
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(DropBehavior),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, PreviewDropCommandPropertyChangedCallBack)
    );

    public static void SetPreviewDropCommand(this UIElement inUIElement, ICommand inCommand) {
        inUIElement.SetValue(PreviewDropCommandProperty, inCommand);
    }

    private static ICommand GetPreviewDropCommand(UIElement inUIElement) {
        return (ICommand)inUIElement.GetValue(PreviewDropCommandProperty);
    }

    private static void PreviewDropCommandPropertyChangedCallBack(
        DependencyObject inDependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs inEventArgs) {
        UIElement uiElement = inDependencyObject as UIElement;
        if (null == uiElement)
            return;

        uiElement.Drop += (sender, args) => {
            GetPreviewDropCommand(uiElement).Execute(args.Data);
            args.Handled = true;
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much putting up the UI whining about it, took another look at the issue again, turns out it was this line here:

```
private static readonly DependencyProperty PreviewDropCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "PreviewDropCommand",
    typeof(ICommand),
    typeof(DropBehavior),
    new PropertyMetadata(null, PreviewDropCommandPropertyChangedCallBack)
);
```

It should have been a `public`, not `private` declaration. Curious that the app runs fine with it, just not the designer (or perhaps not so curious if I knew the inner workings of VS)